# Magento 2 : Discount Codes not Working for Some Customers

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

we are using magento 2.4.5, we have created `coupon codes` and followed all the instructions - we are finding that the codes aren't working for some customers but do work for most.

I have tested them on `desktop`, `mobile`, and `incognito` so I know the code works, but sometimes it doesn't for customers, which is sporadic.
We have tried to see if it is a common browser or device theme and there isn't.

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: Check the code not set by customer group or something? When you try to apply verify all the conditions are fulfill.

Comment: thanks but i have done all of that - it does work on the whole just not for some people and no commonality in the people it doesnt work for to pin point why